# How to create a shared part between two object

Tags: swift, class, reference

`List` and `User` are 2 classes. `List` contains title and a set of movies someone may likes. The class `User` has a `AddList(_: List)` method. It add new movie list to object of `User` type

```
class List {
    var title : String = "General"
    var movies = [String]()

    init(title: String){
        self.title = title
    }

    init(title: String, movies: [String]){
        self.title = title
        self.movies = movies
    }
}

class User {
    private let userID: Int
    let userName: String
    private var movieList = [String: [String]]() // the list is a Dictionaly, the value of the dictionalry is a string array

    init(userID: Int, userName: String){
        self.userID = userID
        self.userName = userName
    }

    func AddList(newMovieList: List) ->  Dictionary<String, [String]> {
        self.movieList.updateValue(newMovieList.movies, forKey: newMovieList.title)
        return self.movieList
    }

}
```

3 movie list had beend inilizied as follow

```
var actionMovieJhon = List(title: "Action", movies: ["The Equalizer", "Mad Max: Fury Road", "Star Wars"])
var actionMovieAnna = List(title: "Action", movies: ["Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice", "American Sniper", "The Martia"])
var shareMovie = List(title: "ShareAction", movies: ["MovieA", "MovieB", "MovieC"])
```

And then 2 `User` objdects `Jhon` and `Anna` with ther own movie list was created

```
var Jhon = User(userID: 1001, userName: "Jhon")
var Anna = User(userID: 1002, userName: "Anna")

Jhon.AddList(actionMovieJhon)
Anna.AddList(actionMovieAnna)
```

**Question**: How can I add the shared movie list (`sharMovie`) into the dictionalry of `Jhon` and `Anna`, so that anything changed in the shared list of `Jhon` will get updated in the side of `Anna` and vice versa.

In anther word, the "dictionary" of `Jhon` and `Anna` has their own part  and shared part. But the shared part is referenced to the same list object

**More Question**: I had feelings that the method `self.movieList.updateValue` is not  `update by reference`

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Because you declared `List` as class, it uses reference semantics. So if you assign the same list for both users, they can both change it. Everything should work as-is.

Comment: I've tried a bit, but I think `self.movieList.updateValue` is not update by reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is based on the sorece code provided by "Swift Apprentice, Beginning programming with Swift 2.2", chapter 14: Classes

```
import Foundation

class List {
    let name: String
    var movies: [String] = []

    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }

    func printList() {
        print("Movie List: \(name)")
        for movie in movies{
            print(movie)
        }
        print("\n")
    }
}


class User {
    var lists: [String: List] = [:]//****

    func addList(list: List){
        lists[list.name] = list
    }

    func listForName(name: String)-> List? {
        print(lists[name]?.movies)
        return lists[name]
    }

}

//create user
let jane = User()
let john = User()
let people = User()

//create list
var johnActionMovie = List(name: "ActionJhon")
var janeActionMovie = List(name: "ActionJane")
var sharedMovie = List(name: "SharedMovie")
var publicIntrest = sharedMovie

//call addList(_:) method on user object
jane.addList(janeActionMovie)
john.addList(johnActionMovie)

jane.addList(sharedMovie)
john.addList(sharedMovie)
people.addList(publicIntrest)


//private part appending
jane.lists["ActionJane"]?.movies.append("janeA")
jane.lists["ActionJane"]?.movies.append("janeB")
jane.lists["ActionJane"]?.movies.append("janeC")


john.lists["ActionJhon"]?.movies.append("johnA")
john.lists["ActionJhon"]?.movies.append("johnB")
john.lists["ActionJhon"]?.movies.append("johnB")

//Shared part appending
john.lists["SharedMovie"]?.movies.append("shareA")
jane.lists["SharedMovie"]?.movies.append("shareB")
people.lists["SharedMovie"]?.movies.append("shareC")


//print out the result
john.listForName("ActionJhon")
john.listForName("SharedMovie")

jane.listForName("ActionJane")
jane.listForName("SharedMovie")

people.listForName("SharedMovie")


//further check
print(jane.lists["ShareMovie"] === people.lists["ShareMovie"])
print(jane.lists["ActionJane"] === john.lists["ActionList"])
```